# How do I prove a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, cauchy-sequences

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function on A of $\Bbb{R}$. How do I show that if $a_n$ is Cauchy, then $f(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

This is what I have worked on, but it does not quite make sense since I feel like I didn't really use the given condition that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Let $\epsilon>0$, $f$ is uniformly continuous, so there exists$\delta>0$ st $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for $|x-y|<\delta$.

Since $a_n$ is Cauchy, there exists $N>0$ such that $|a_n-a_m|<\delta$ for $m,n>N$

Hence$|f(a_n)-f(a_m)|<\epsilon$ for $m,n>N$. So $f(a_n)$ is Cauchy

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm assuming when you say "$A$ of $\Bbb{R}$" you mean "a subset $A$ of $\Bbb{R}$".

Comment: Is the converse true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your proof looks good.  You use uniform continuity to claim that for *every* $n,m>N$, $\vert f(a_n)-f(a_m)\vert<\epsilon$.  If you only had continuity, $\delta$ would depend on $x$ and hence you couldn't claim that $\vert a_n-a_m\vert<\delta\Longrightarrow\vert f(a_n)-f(a_m)\vert<\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$.

**Additional comment**

If $A$ is assumed to be closed, then uniform continuity is not necessary (only "pointwise" continuity).  This is since if $A$ is closed, $(a_n)$ is guaranteed to converge to some $a\in A$.  Then, $f$ will be continuous at $a$ and the proof can be modified accordingly without using uniform continuity.

Comment: Couldn't you use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is complete to say that $a_n$ Cauchy $\implies$ it converges, and then use the $\delta$ that works for its limit?

Comment: If I'm interpreting OP's language correctly, we only have $f$ defined on an arbitrary subset $A\subset\Bbb{R}$.  For instance, $A$ could be $(0,1)$ which is not complete (hence $f$ might not be continuous at the limit point of $(a_n)$).

Comment: @icurays1: I do not agree with you idea. The uniformly continuous mapping necessarily preservs the Cauchy sequence from one metric space to another regardless of closed or open while pointwise continuous can't! The key point is that if A is closed with pointwise continuous, then {an} will still converge but not be a Cauchy sequence!

Comment: @icurays1 Yes, since a continuous function on a closed subset is always automatically uniformly continuous. You aren't really making the conditions less stringent, just rewording them.

Comment: @MichaelAngelo continuous function on closed set is uniformly continuous??? R is closed in R, no?

Comment: @HritRoy I stand corrected, I must have meant closed and bounded (or compact in a more general setting, not sure if that matters), I think the result is known as the Heine-Cantor theorem.

Comment: @Bearandbunny How is a convergent sequence not Cauchy?

Comment: @HritRoy Every convergent sequence in a metric space is Cauchy

Comment: @Bearandbunny I know that, hence the comment. You wrote {an} will converge but not be a Cauchy sequence

Comment: @HritRoy Sorry. It's been a long time. My thought was incorrect. I was a newbie on real at that time.