# $f$ uniformly continuous , $a_n$ Cauchy $\Rightarrow f(a_n)$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, cauchy-sequences

Let $I$ be an interval and let $f: I\to \mathbb{ R}$ be uniformly continuous on I. Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $I$. Prove that $\{f(a_n)\} $is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense. The question does, however. Write down the definitions of a Cauchy sequence and a uniformly continuous function right next to each other. Look at them for a bit.

Comment: [How do I prove a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252538/how-do-i-prove-a-uniformly-continuous-function-preserves-cauchy-sequences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$, Since $f$ is uniformly continuous,$\exists \delta>0 \ni |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ Whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.

$a_n$ is Cauchy, so $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ni |a_n-a_m|<\delta \forall m,n>N$

So $|f(a_n)-f(a_m)|<\epsilon \forall m,n>N$. So $\{f(a_n)\}$ is Cauchy