# If A is bounded and not compact, prove thrrr is a continuous function on A that is not uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, real-numbers, uniform-continuity

If A is bounded and not compact, prove thrrr is a continuous function on A that is not uniformly continuous.

I found the same question, but I am not understanding the function definition of why it's not u.c or how the not compactness criterion is used.
[image: number 24]

Comment: According to my book, it's not uniformly continuous

Comment: Exact quote of your book?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I posted the picture

Comment: The exact quote that is on that page is "Prove that there is a function that is continuous on $A$ but not uniformly continuous." That does _not_ mean that every continuous function is non-uniformly continuous. It just means that a continuous function is not necessarily uniformly continuous, but it could be.

Comment: $\exists\ne\forall$. Edit the question to correct the statement.

Comment: Is $A$ a subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Arthur yes I believe so!

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla edited.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let be $x_0\not\in A$ but limit of a sequence of points of $A$ (alternatively, $x_0\in\partial A\setminus A$). Consider the function
$f(x) = 1/|x - x_0|$.

Comment: My problem is showing that f is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @user338365, idea: uniformly continuous functions preserve Cauchy sequences (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252538/how-do-i-prove-a-uniformly-continuous-function-preserves-cauchy-sequences). Construct a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ s.t. $(f(x_n))$ isn't a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: ok I see now that contracting a Cauchy sequence in A with the limit point not being in A.

Comment: but I am having trouble showing f(Xn) is not Cauchy.

Comment: @user338365, is unbounded.