# If continuity preserves convergence, and Cauchy sequences are convergent sequences, why do we need uniform continuity to preserve Cauchy sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, intuition

In $\mathbb R$, all Cauchy sequences are convergent and all convergent sequences are Cauchy. So, why isn't continuity enough to preserve Cauchy sequences?

A function is continuous iff it preserves convergent sequences.

A sequence is convergent iff it is Cauchy.

So, why doesn't it follow that continuous functions preserve Cauchy sequences?

Comment: Continuity of what, you meant $(a_n)$ is Cauchy then so is $(f(a_n))$ ? What if $f$ is continuous at $l = \lim_n a_n$ ?

Comment: Think of $f(x) = 1/x$ on $(0,1)$ and $a_n = 1/n$.

Comment: Ok, we have $a_n \to 0$, $f(a_n)=1/a_n=n$. So, $f(a_n) \to \infty$. What does this tell me?

Comment: "All Cauchy sequences are convergent" False.

Comment: Ok, I'm considering $\mathbb R$ only.

Comment: @zhw. All cauchy sequences are convergent in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @AlJebr With respect to the example, we have $f(a_n)-f(a_m)=n-m$. This is the point.

Comment: @AlJebr Yes of course. But who said we were in $\mathbb R?$ How about continuous functions on $(0,1)?$

Comment: Is this correct? Suppose $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. So, if $x_n$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$, converging to $x_0 \in (0,1)$, then $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. Since $x_n \to x_0$, then $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Also since $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$ then $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*why isn't continuity enough to preserve Cauchy sequences?*

Because, in general, it is not given that the limit of the sequence belongs to the domain of the function.

The implication
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n= x\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)= f(x)$$
requires $x_n,x\in D(f)$. Thus, if $x\notin D(f)$, this argument does not work (a counterexample was given in the comments of your post). In fact, in this case we need an extra condition (see the first comment below).

---

### Edit

Let us analyze your argument:

> **Claim:** Continuous functions preserve Cauchy sequences.
>
> *Poof:* Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$. Let $f:X\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence.
>
> We want to show that $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy.
>
> 1. As a (real) sequence is convergent iff it is Cauchy, there exists $x_0\in\mathbb R$ such that
>      $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0.\tag{$*$}$$
> 2. As a function is continuous iff it preserves convergent sequences, there exists $L\in\mathbb R$ such that
>      $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L.$$
> 3. As a (real) sequence is convergent iff it is Cauchy, we conclude that $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy.

The problem is step 2 which, in general, does not follow from $(*)$. If $x_0$ belongs to $X$, then it is true (with $L=f(x_0)$) but in general we cannot guarantee the existence of $L$.

Comment: (we need continuity on the closed set $\overline{D(f)}$, for $D(f)$ bounded it is the same as uniform continuity)

Comment: @reuns Thanks, I edited my post.

Comment: But what is wrong with the implications: In $\mathbb R$, $x_n$ Cauchy implies $x_n$ convergent implies $f(x_n)$ convergent implies $f(x_n) Cauchy? Doesn't this mean continuous functions preserve Cauchy?

Comment: @AlJebr Nothing. See the **Additional comment** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252551/70305).

Comment: @AlJebr There is nothing wrong if the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @AlJebr I must say *"for every sequence $a_n \to l$, $f(a_n) \to f(l)$"* is the very **definition** of *"$f$ is continuous at $l$"*. Now $f(x) = 1/x, x \in (0,1]$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$, thus it is not continuous at $0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(1/n)$ diverges.

Comment: I don't understand. If $0$ is not in the domain, why are we considering it?

Comment: @AlJebr Because it is the limit of the given Cauchy sequence.

Comment: $1/n$ is a sequence converging to $0$. So, it is a Cauchy sequence converging to $0$. But $0$ is not a point of $(0,1)$, so the fact that $f(a_n)$ doesn't converge to $f(0)$ does not tell us anything.

Comment: @AlJebr Explicitly and rigorously, what do you mean by "A function is continuous iff it preserves convergent sequences"?

Comment: Let $f$ be a function defined on $D$. Then $f$ is continuous if and only if for every sequence $x_n \to x_0 \in D$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$.

Comment: For $f(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1)$, we know $f$ is not continuous at $0$ because $0$ is not even in the domain.

Comment: @AlJebr see my edit. Step 2 is wrong, right? In the sentences that you wrote, the fact that the Cauchy sequence converges to a point of the domain is a hidden assumption (not fulfilled in general, as shown by that example).

Comment: Ok, so the problem arises at limit points? For the $f(x) =1/x$ defined on $(0,1)$ example, although $0$ is a limit point and so there exists a sequence $x_n \to 0$, we cannot conclude $\lim f(x_n)$ exists?

Comment: @AlJebr Exactly. The argument works if all limit points of the domain belong to the domain (i.e. if the domain is closed).

Comment: @reuns exactly. Nice conclusion.