# Uniformly continuous functions and the preservation of Cauchy sequences

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

A function which maps a metric space into a metric space is continuous if and only if all convergent sequences are mapped to convergent sequences. Can we think a uniformly continuous function as the one which preserves “cauchy-ness” of a sequence, that is every Cauchy sequence is mapped to Cauchy sequence? Please elaborate more on this.

Comment: Such condition is weaker than uniform continuity. It is called Cauchy continuity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function

Comment: Wait so it’s a necessary condition for a mapping to be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Yep: it is necessary, but not sufficient. In general , for a map between metric spaces you have $$\mbox{uniform continuous $\Rightarrow$ Cauchy continuous $\Rightarrow$ continuous}$$

Answer (score 4):

No, the two concepts are not equivalent. For example, the function $f(x) = x^2$  on the real line preserves Cauchy sequences, but is not uniformly continuous. Indeed, any continuous function from   $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ preserves Cauchy sequences because in $\mathbb{R}$, being a Cauchy sequence is equivalent to being convergent, and continuous functions preserve convergence.

References:

- [How do I prove a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252538/how-do-i-prove-a-uniformly-continuous-function-preserves-cauchy-sequences)
- [If continuity preserves convergence, and Cauchy sequences are convergent sequences, why do we need uniform continuity to preserve Cauchy sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506933/if-continuity-preserves-convergence-and-cauchy-sequences-are-convergent-sequenc)