# Prove that uniform continuous function preserves Cauchy Sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

We would show that uniform continuous functions preserve Cauchy sequences. That is,

$$
\textrm{If f is a uniformly continuous function on S, and}~s_n~\textrm{is Cauchy sequence on S, then}~(f(s_n))~\textrm{is also a Cauchy Sequence}
$$

Here is the proof,

$$\textrm{Since, f is uniformly continuous on S, we have}$$

$$\textrm{for each}~ \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta_{\epsilon}, ~\textrm{such that} ~ \forall x, y \in S, ~ |x-y| \lt \delta_{\epsilon} \implies |f(x)-f(y)\lt \epsilon$$

$$since (s_n) ~\textrm{is a Cauchy sequence, we have an N such that} ~ n, m \gt N \implies |s_n - s_m| \lt \delta_{\epsilon}$$

$$\textrm{since} ~s_n, s_m \in S~ ~  |s_n - s_m| \lt \delta_{\epsilon} \implies |f(s_n) - (s_m)| \lt \epsilon$$

$$\forall n,m \gt N~\textrm{we have} |f(s_n) - f(s_m) | \lt \epsilon$$

Is my proof well-written?

P.S. I do not know why the latex code is not rendered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252538/how-do-i-prove-a-uniformly-continuous-function-preserves-cauchy-sequences)

Comment: @geetha290krm This a "solution-verification" question, and I posted it to get reviews on my logic of this proof as I wrote without reading any proof of it from anywhere, else the proves are numerous and can be found in any textbook. .

Comment: The logic of your proof looks fine. If it matters, I personally prefer to see "for every," "there exists," and "implies" written out rather than as symbols, and explanations written in complete, punctuated sentences.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks for your comments.